# Shell: tar exit code 126

Tags: bash, shell, wget, tar, gzip

So I have this script here called `updaterct2.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="./newopenrct2.tar.gz"
$(wget $1 -O $FILE)
$(tar xvzf $FILE)
echo $?
```

and the only file inside `./newopenrct2.tar.gz` is a folder titled `OpenRCT2` which has all the contents. Running this script produces

```
./updaterct2.sh: line 4: OpenRCT2/: Is a directory
126
```

even though it properly extracts the files...

As a test I tried modifying `updaterct2.sh` to create the directory

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="./newopenrct2.tar.gz"
DIR="./OpenRCT2"
$(wget $1 -O $FILE)
$(tar xvzf $FILE -C $DIR)
echo $?
```

But it still produces the same result.

Running the commands in terminal

```
wget http://cdn.limetric.com/games/openrct2/0.2.0/develop/2e36253/9/OpenRCT2-0.2.0-develop-2e36253-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -O ./newopenrct2.tar.gz
tar xvzf ./newopenrct2.tar.gz
```

works without any errors and outputs

```
./newopenrct2.tar.g 100%[===================>]  33.16M  9.96MB/s    in 3.7s
...
OpenRCT2/
OpenRCT2/doc/
OpenRCT2/doc/changelog.txt
OpenRCT2/doc/licence.txt
OpenRCT2/doc/readme.txt
...
```

I don't think the permissions should be a problem, they are as follows

```
-rw-rw-r--   newopenrct2.tar.gz
-rwxrwxr-x   updaterct2.sh
```

What exactly is going wrong in the bash script? Why is it giving a non-zero exit code?

Comment: You mistaked using `$()`.

Comment: What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistaked using the `$()` grammar.

> Command substitution reassigns the output of a command [1] or even multiple commands; it literally plugs the command output into another context. [2]
>
> classic form of command substitution uses backquotes (`...`). Commands within backquotes (backticks) generate command-line text.
>
> $(...) form has superseded backticks for command substitution.

Then, line 4 `$(tar xvzf $FILE)` will try to execute **the output** of `tar xvzf $FILE`, which begins with the line `OpenRCT2/`, comes from the extracting progress. This results in, actually, executing a directory, which reply you `Is a directory`.

To fix this, just simply remove all the `$()` like this below, remaining the original command.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="./newopenrct2.tar.gz"
wget $1 -O $FILE
tar xvzf $FILE
echo $?
```

For the error code `126`, this comes from actually the error of executing the directory, see [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

> 126   Command invoked cannot execute

[1]: [Example 11-8. A grep replacement for binary files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#BINGREP)

[2]: [Example 11-27. Using command substitution to generate the case variable](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testbranch.html#CASECMD)

Comment: Ah thank you! I've had such a big headache over such a little syntax error

Comment: @SamsonClose You may look at `man tar` and found the error code can only be 0, 1 or 2, this shows that the error code 126 will not be related to `tar`.

Comment: There are still some bugs here on account of missing quotes. If `$1` or `$FILE` contained spaces, it would be split into multiple arguments. Correct code would be `wget "$1" -O "$FILE"` and `tar xvzf "$FILE"` (well, *best-practices* code wouldn't be naming a variable as `FILE` either; all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed safe for applications to redefine; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: ...also, please *don't* link the ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated information. [The bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are far better resources; for the former on exit status, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Shocked for me to know of "ABS is the W3Schools of bash". I will remember your warnings. Thank you. However I can't get enough information to update my answer, since The bash-hackers' wiki may be temporarily down or banned in my country.